# Redis: fan out news feeds in list or sorted set?

Tags: redis

I'm caching fan-out news feeds with Redis in the following way:

each feed activity is a key/value, like activity:id where the value is a JSON string of the data.

each news feed is currently a list, the key is feed:user:user_id and the list contains the keys of the relevant activities.

to retrieve a news feed I use for example: 'sort feed:user:user_id by nosort get * limit 0 40'

I'm considering changing the feed to a sorted set where the score is the activity's timestamp, this way the feed is always sorted by time.

I read http://arindam.quora.com/Redis-sorted-sets-and-lists-Pertaining-to-Newsfeed which recommend using lists because of the time complexity of sorted sets, but by keep using lists I have to take care of the insert order, 
inserting a past story requires to iterate through the list and finding the right index to push to. (which can cause new problems in distributed environments).

should I keep using lists or go for sorted sets?

is there a way to retrieve the news feed instantly from a sorted set, (like with the sort ... get * command for a list) or does it have to be zrange and then iterating through the results and getting each value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, sorted sets are very fast and powerful. They seem a much better match for your requirements than `SORT` operations. The time complexity is often misunderstood. [O(log(N))](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/12/07/comp-sci-101-big-o-notation/) is very fast, and scales just fine. We use it for tens of millions of members in one sorted set. Retrieval and insertion is sub-millisecond.

Use [`ZRANGEBYSCORE key min max WITHSCORES [LIMIT offset count]`](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) to get your results.

Depending on how you store the timestamps as 'scores', [ZREVRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebyscore) might be better.

A small remark about the timestamps: Sorted set `SCORES` which don't need a decimal part should be using 15 digits or less. So the `SCORE` has to stay in the range -999999999999999 to 999999999999999. Note: These limits exist because Redis server actually stores the score (float) as a redis-string representation internally.

I therefore recommend this format, converted to [Zulu Time](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/info/zulu.htm): -20140313122802 for second-precision. You may add 1 digit for 100ms-precision, but no more **if** you want no loss in precision. It's still a float64 by the way, so loss of precision could be fine in some scenarios, but your case fits in the 'perfect precision' range, so that's what I recommend.

If your data expires within 10 years, you can also skip the three first digits (CCY of CCYY), to achieve .0001 second precision.

I suggest negative scores here, so you can use the simpler `ZRANGEBYSCORE` instead of the `REV` one. You can use *`-inf`* as the start score (minus infinity) and `LIMIT 0 100` to get the top 100 results.

Two sorted set `members` *(or `'keys'` but that's ambiguous since the sorted set is also a key in itself)* may share a `score`, that's no problem, the results within an identical `score` are alphabetical.

Hope this helps, TW

**Edit after chat**

The OP wanted to collect data (using a `ZSET`) from different keys (`GET`/`SET` or `HGET`/`HSET` keys). `JOIN` can do that for you, `ZRANGEBYSCORE` can't.
The preferred way of doing this, is a simple Lua script. The Lua script is executed on the server. In the example below I use `EVAL` for simplicity, in production you would use `SCRIPT EXISTS`, `SCRIPT LOAD` and `EVALSHA`. Most client libraries have some bookkeeping logic built-in, so you don't upload the script each time.

Here's an `example.lua`:

```lua
local r={}
local zkey=KEYS[1]
local a=redis.call('zrangebyscore', zkey, KEYS[2], KEYS[3], 'withscores', 'limit', 0, KEYS[4])
for i=1,#a,2 do
  r[i]=a[i+1]
  r[i+1]=redis.call('get', a[i])
end
return r
```

You use it like this *(raw example, not coded for performance)*:

```
redis-cli -p 14322 set activity:1 act1JSON
redis-cli -p 14322 set activity:2 act2JSON
redis-cli -p 14322 zadd feed 1 activity:1
redis-cli -p 14322 zadd feed 2 activity:2 

redis-cli -p 14322 eval '$(cat example.lua)' 4 feed '-inf' '+inf' 100
```

Result:

```
1) "1"
2) "act1JSON"
3) "2"
4) "act2JSON"
```

Comment: I use UNIX timestamps (10 digits) as scores. can I get the feed directly from a sorted set? with a list I can do `sort feed by nosort get *....'

Comment: Ofcourse you can. 10 digits is less than 15. I put some extra info in my post on big-O by the way.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answers, how do I get the feed directly? (the values of the actual activities and not just their keys). 'ZRANGE' will return the keys with or without scores..

Comment: ZRANGEBYSCORE also returns the keys. If you use WITHSCORES, it also returns your timestamps. Which is useful when paginating, because LIMIT OFFSET has a small performance penalty (if you go into the 10s of thousands). If you want to point to a HSET from the ZSET: use a simple Lua script to aggregate the results server-side.

Comment: My question is: the sorted set contains keys of activities, for example activity:1, activity:2, ... the score of each one of those activities is the timestamp. is there a way with sorted set to get the content of the activities directly? or I need to use 'ZRANGE' and then iterate through the results and get each one of them? 
With a list its possible using the 'SORT' command..

Comment: Have you [__played around__](http://try.redis-db.com/) with it? You don't need `ZRANGE`. Just `ZADD` and `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE`. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49650/discussion-between-gal-ben-haim-and-tw-bert)