# Open source in-memory & persistent & distributed time series database

Tags: redis, time-series, distributed, in-memory-database, in-memory

I am looking to write a distribution application that will need a time series in-memory database (that needs to be persistent as well).
I will need to do various analytics on this time series data like aggregation, filtering, etc.
And ideally i want to scale these seperately.

Meaning something like lets say there is a process that appends to these time series data and then exposes this data to a set of applications (processes which are for various analytics) like say a shared memory handle. 
The application will need to go over the time series mostly as readonly in order to compute the analytics. So once can see this as one process that will be writing (adding/modifying the time series). And other applications which will  be accesseing those time series data as a read only to evaluate analytics.

Further i need the timeseries data to be persisent and preferrably persistent and distributed cache if possible (something based on redis possibly).

I would like to explore what alternatives I have.

Answer (score 0):

Redis seems like a good option for your use case. You can start simple with only one master and no slaves. If you use non-transactional [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining), redis-server will handle concurrency, so clients can read in between.

Use [`ZADD`](http://redis.io/commands/zadd) and [`ZRANGEBYSCORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) for your timeseries data.
You might also want to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375662/redis-fan-out-news-feeds-in-list-or-sorted-set).

When you add a couple of slaves later, you can leave these in read-only mode, and let the read-only clients gather data from those slaves. You might even do some pre-aggregation in Lua on the server. The real data analytics should be done in a client process.

If it's a lot of data, you'll probably want to serialize it in [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/) format. Server-side Lua scripts can serialize/deserialize this. This format is very memory efficient.

Hope this helps, TW

Answer (score 0):

The handling of time series data seems to be suitable for the Druid engine. 
Druid provides fast response to the OLAP data engine for time series data. 
In addition, metatron Discovery, a Druid-based analysis platform. Check it out!.