# Queue-like data structure in Redis

Tags: dictionary, redis, node-redis

I need to save my data in queue-like data structure in Redis DB. How can I achieve this. Please help.

My data looks like

```
KEY | {TIMESTAMP1 - LOCATION1, TIMESTAMP2 - LOCATION2, .... }
```

Comment: Have you considered using Redis' LIST data type? You can use LPUSH to enqueue and RPOP to dequeue.

Comment: can you please suggest me which is the best data-type to use in chat like applicatins or applications in which we have to deliver data in sequence in which sender sends ? thanks

Comment: Have you considered the pubsub mechanism redis offers?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375662/redis-fan-out-news-feeds-in-list-or-sorted-set/22377007#22377007)